# Glyphicons are different colour on iOS compared to Android

Tags: ios, cordova, ios9, font-awesome, ios9.1

For example:

```
<a target="_blank" href="#Home" class="needsclick btn-header-xs btn-header-md btn-header-lg">
   <span class="fa fa-home header-glyph"></span>
</a>
```

The 'btn-header-*' only applies padding.

```
.header-glyph, header-glyph:active, header-glyph:focus, header-glyph:hover,
header-glyph:visited {
    color: #428bca !important;
    font-size: 25px !important
}
```

Android this is blue (#428bca), yet on iOS this is an orange colour.

Can't see anything behind the scenes that would make it inherit this colour.

Looking for a platform specific issue that can be hopefully overridden?? I am developing on iOS 9.0.2 also.

Comment: Looks like a css issue, where Safari (iOS browser) doesn't apply the blue color. Could you share a fiddle?

Comment: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vrhpcr2z/). Yeah seems like safari, but I can't see the inherited style that is affecting it, as the css states that it is blue even though its orange. JsFiddle isnt replicating it though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was asked to update my iOS from **9.0.2** to **9.1.0**. This styling issue cannot be replicated any longer. Looked at the release notes out of curiosity, but nothing that specific.

Comment: Weirdest issue of my life.